# find all array value which match with a sub-string and update that duplicate array value using loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

from an array, I need to get all value that matches this "filters" sub-string. after getting all matches values from that array I need to check duplicate value based on "filters[x]" after that I need to update all duplicate value using a loop.

```
     //input array
         array=["filters[maker]", "Samsung&filters[maker]", 
"Vivo&filters[maker]", 
"Oppo&filters[release_year]", 
"unspecified&filters[os]", 
"IOS&filters[os]","android"]
        //output array
         [
"filters[maker][0]",
"Samsung&filters[maker][1]",
"Vivo&filters[maker][2]",
"Oppo&filters[release_year][0]",
"unspecified&filters[os][0]",
"IOS&filters[os][1]",
"android"
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my 2 cents on this

```js
const array = [
    "filters[maker]", 
    "Samsung&filters[maker]", 
    "Vivo&filters[maker]", 
    "Oppo&filters[release_year]", 
    "unspecified&filters[os]", 
    "IOS&filters[os]",
    "android"
];

const lookup = Object.create(null);
const re = /\[(.+)\]/;

const output = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const match = curr.match(re);
    const key = match && match.length && match[1];
    if (key) {
        if (!lookup[key]) {
            lookup[key] = 1;
        } else {
            lookup[key] += 1;
        }
        
        const currentEntry = curr + '[' + (lookup[key] - 1) + ']';
        acc.push(currentEntry);
    } else {
        acc.push(curr);
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Hello brother,

what if the situation--
"filters[X]" need to compare this
//input array 
array=["filters[maker]", "Samsung&filters[maker]", 
"Vivo&filters[maker]", 
"Oppo&filters[release_year]", 
"unspecified&filters[os]", 
"IOS&filters[os]","android"]

//output array
[
"filters[maker][0]",
"Samsung&filters[maker][1]",
"Vivo&filters[maker][2]",
"Oppo&filters[release_year][0]",
"unspecified&filters[os][0]",
"IOS&filters[os][1]","android"
]

Comment: @TanvirAhamed can you update this scenario in the question

Comment: @ Kunal Mukherjee thank you, brother, for your feedback. question updated. please, check

Comment: @ Kunal Mukherjee thank you, brother, for your kind feedback. question updated. please, check.

Comment: @ Kunal Mukherjee thank you brother, you help me a lot. I new here so that I can not give u the upvote.

Answer (score 0):

```js
array=["filter[maker]",
   "filter[maker]",
   "filter[maker]",
   "filter[release_year]",
   "filter[release_year]",
   "filter[os]",
   "jodu",
   "modu"
]

// create an object as a counter with "filter" keys 
var filters = array.reduce((r,v) => {
   if (!v.match(/^filter\[\w+\]/)) return r
   return {[v]:0,...r}
},{})
console.log(filters)

// create the output
output = array.map(v => { // map the input array
   if (v in filters) { // check if "v" is a filter
      var n = filters[v]++ // if so, assign it ti "n" and after increment the counter
      v = `${v}[${n}]` // update the string
   }
   return v
})
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i< array.length; i++){
  if(array[i].startsWith("filter")){
    console.log(array[i])
    window[array[i]+"var"] = array[i];
    if (window[array[i]+"var"] == array[i]){
      outputarray[i] = array[i] + "["+i+"]"
    }
  }
}
console.log(updatedArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object to store how many times an element has appeared so far when looping with `Array#map`.

```js
let  array=["filter[maker]",
               "filter[maker]",
               "filter[maker]",
               "filter[release_year]",
               "filter[release_year]",
               "filter[os]",
               "jodu",
               "modu"
               ];
const freq = {}, res = array.map(x => 
     (freq[x] = (freq[x] || 0) + 1, 
       x.startsWith("filter") ? x + "[" + (freq[x] - 1) + "]" : x));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match your regex with a `String.prototype.match()` function. In this particular code you do `found = item.match(/filter\[(.*)\]/);`

And you keep the index of the matched item in an object and just do a lookup

```js
 //input array
array=[
  "filter[maker]",
  "filter[maker]",
  "filter[maker]",
  "filter[release_year]",
  "filter[release_year]",
  "filter[os]",
  "jodu",
  "modu"
]

//output array
filter_key_map = {};
outputarray = array.map(item => {
  found = item.match(/filter\[(.*)\]/);
  key = found && found[1];
  
  if (key) {
    filter_key_map[key] = filter_key_map[key] || 0
    return `${item}[${filter_key_map[key]++}]`
  }
  return item
})

console.log(outputarray)
```